# Buttons, simplifying if statements into a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, button

So I have a simple task that checks if the value for the text of a button is blank and if it is it makes the button hidden. the string for the text inside the text box is (ex. Time_A_) (set to button after) and the corresponding button name is the same minus the underscore (ex. Time_A). What I would like to do is simplify this code to use something like a for loop instead of the 12 if statements.

```
if (Time_A_ == "")
{
    Time_A.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
if (Time_B_ == "")
{
    Time_B.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
if (Time_C_ == "")
{
    Time_C.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
if (Time_D_ == "")
{
    Time_D.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
if (Location_A_ == "")
{
    Location_A.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
if (Location_B_ == "")
{
    Location_B.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
if (Location_C_ == "")
{
    Location_C.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
if (Location_D_ == "")
{
    Location_D.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
if (Date_A_ == "")
{
    Date_A.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
if (Date_B_ == "")
{
    Date_B.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
if (Date_C_ == "")
{
    Date_C.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
if (Date_D_ == "")
{
    Date_D.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't have a lot of separate variables, but should instead have a collection...

Comment: what do you mean? like an array?

Comment: Yes, or a list. Either way, you could then iterate over all the buttons and do the same thing for each of them.

Answer (score 5):

You should add them to a panel and then loop over all the controls in the panel

```
foreach(var control in this.panelName.Controls.Where(ctrl => string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrl.Text))
    control.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

There doesn't appear to be any need for the separate text variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest registering an event-handler for the `TextChanged`-Event on your buttons which would look like this:

```
private void button1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    button.Visible = (button.Text != String.Empty);
}
```

This way you do not have to change the layout of your forms.